# converting an int to blank spaces in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a user input integer into blank spaces. For example, when int = 3, there will be 3 blank spaces as the output. I will need to convert the numbers 0-15 to 0-15 blank spaces. I am new to programming so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: `int n;scanf("%d", &n);printf("%*s", n, "");`

Comment: 1) Get input 2) Use a loop to print spaces There isn't any need for conversions here.

Answer (score 0):

You had to read about the [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) function

```
int x;
if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1)
    printf("%*s/ <--- there are %d white spaces behind\n", x, "", x);
else
    printf("wrong input, an integer expected\n");
```